# Let $X = A \setminus \{\frac{e_1}{2}\}$. Show that $X$ is connected, but not path-connected.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^2$ be a union of lines $J_n=[0, e_1 + \frac{e_2}{n}], n \in \Bbb N$ and the line $[0,e_1]$. Let $X = A \setminus \{\frac{e_1}{2}\}$. Show that $X$ is connected, but not path-connected. Here $e_n$ is the standard unit vector.

To show that $X$ is connected I've tried a contradiction approach. To suppose that $X= G \cup H$ for $G, H$ open in $\Bbb R^2$ and $G \cap H = \emptyset$, $G \cap X \ne \emptyset, H \cap X \ne \emptyset, G \cap H \cap X = \emptyset$.

But I don't see how I can get a contradiction from here since I cannot justify to myself why couldn't I express this set with union of sets containing different lines?

Actually wouldn't they all have to contain the origin $0$ so it would be impossible to have $G \cap H = \emptyset$?

Comment: $J_n$ seems to be independent of the value of $n$…

Comment: Oh sorry $n$ should be in the denominator of $\frac{e_2}{2}$.

Comment: Do you know about path components and how they relate to connected components?

Comment: Connectedness is easy to see. The union $B$ of all $J_n$ is (path) connected. The closure of $B$ in $A' = A \setminus \{e_1/2\}$ is $A'$.